# Compare File A and File B (partial match) on Linux

Tags: linux, grep, compare

First of all, thank you for taking your time reading this and trying to solve my problem. Now to the problem:

I have two txt files "serials" and "list". I need to compare the file "list" with the file "serials" to find out if I still have any serials left for the particular software so basically show those names (in my example: MS Office 2016, 2013, 365) that has no match in the file "serials" so I do not offer them for sale anymore.

I tried to use the "grep" command

```
grep -v -F -x list.txt serials.txt
```

however there seems to be problem that the file "serials" is in a format:

**MS Office 2016 - XXXX-XXXX-XXXX**

**MS Office 2013 - XXXX-XXXX-XXXX**

**Ms Office 365 - XXXX-XXXX-XXXX**

while the file "list" is simple like this:

**MS Office 2016**

**MS Office 2013**

**Ms Office 365**

Can anyone help me how to specify the command to get an output of the names that are not part of the serials.txt anymore?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself. Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I put the code that I tried to use, I am a Linux beginner so it might seem that I did not put any effort, but I've been trying to make it work for almost an hour. Desired output was part of the original post, however I made a summary in the end. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few ways to do it using the Shell/Perl/Python etc.
If I understand your requirements correctly, here is one option in Bash:

```
cat list | while read product
do
    num_lic=$( grep -wc $product serials )
    if [ $num_lic -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo $product
    fi
done
```

Comment: Sounds like you're working on some kind of inventory. You should perhaps look at one of the open source products available, or at least storing this type of info in a database. Will make your life simpler ;-)

Comment: I need to compare 300 product names to 1500 serials and see if I did not forget to delete anything during the times. Going to test out your code and see if it works, thank you very much, sir!

Comment: Hopefully there are no spelling errors in your files as they could cause issues.
If you want to make the grep case insensitive, add a `-i` to it.

ie. `num_lic=$( grep -iwc $product serials )`